# (SOLVED) String impossible to translate Civicontribute

Tags: civicontribute

It seems that i can't translate, even within word replacement, the 'Credit Card Information' string. I am using Stripe as payment processor. Would this be related to them and not CiviCRM?
Has anybody successfully translated it?

[image: Payment processor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question.

The word "Information" is being translated SEPARATELY from the words "Credit Card". You can see this if you switch the language to Spanish for example. It will then say "Informacion Credit Card".

But the "Credit Card" part is intended to be coming from the label for the payment type as defined in the admin section for payment methods. However the code in CRM_Core_Payment::getPaymentTypeLabel() has a comment that this was never finished, and so it has the words "Credit Card" hardcoded.

If you want a hack then you can edit the line in templates/CRM/Core/BillingBlock.tpl where it says `<legend>{$paymentTypeLabel}</legend>` to say `<legend>Desired Text</legend>`, but this will get overridden each time you upgrade.